# How to create a component without any icon on the form (Like TFloatAnimation)

Tags: delphi

How to create a component without any icon on the form at the design time, Like `TFloatAnimation` for example.

Comment: Still not very familiar with FireMonkey, and I haven't seen that behavior in the VCL, but my guess is that the visual components are only those that have the form as their owner. Since you can add a TFloatAnimation and attach it to existing components, I guess that that component is made the owner  of the animation, and that component is also the one responsible for streaming the animation properties to it's DFM. In short, I don't think TFloatAnimation itself is not really special, but it's the way it's added to another component instead of to the form directly. But, a guess, hence comment.

Comment: @GolezTrol: no unfortunately not like this :( I try to duplicate the same structure as TFloatAnimation but I still view the icon on the form :(

Comment: I don't  know what the purpose is of a 'stand alone' TFloatAnimation. Just did some reading up, and it seems to be for animating a specific property. If you put some control, say, a button on a form, select  propertly like width, and open the dropdown in the object inspector, it allows you to create a new floatanimation. If you then look at the DFM, the new animation is indeed stored as sub-object of the button, and has it's PropertyName property filled in.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes exactly, I have exactly the same behavior except that with my component I have a visual icon on the form :(